# Balloon Pop Animation

Tags: animation, cloth-simulation, effects

How can I make a balloon pop in Blender?

Here's a reference:

[image: 3D animation of a "2020" balloon popping]

I've seen the "ClothFX" add-on, but I couldn't get this result with it.

Comment: Just a small observation: the reference isn't realistic, my extensive study of slo-mo baloon popping videos on tik-tok tells me a baloon doesn't pop to many small pieces - it rips but tends to stay a single piece. I say this because either the reference is wrong, or you're fine with solutions being stylized as opposed to maximizing realism.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create the balloon shape with the help of *Cloth* simulation (enable the *Pressure* and also the *Self Collisions* options):

[image]

When you're glad with the shape, apply the *Cloth* modifier, animate the inflate effect with a shapekeys and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>:

[image]

Duplicate the object, make it invisible at the frame you want it to explode. Use the *Cell Fracture* operation to cut off the copy in several pieces, put their origin at their geometry, give them *Rigid Body* physic, cut off the *Gravity* in the Scene panel, create a *Force Field* > *Force* to make the pieces explode, make them visible when the object is supposed to explode:

[image]

Comment: you're a legend

Comment: how do you make objects visible/invisible in an animation?

Comment: You can keyframe the Disable in Renders option of the object in the Outliner (camera icon), you can also keyframe it in the Object panel > Visibility > Show in Renders. For the multiple pieces you'll create the keyframes for one of these pieces only then copy the animation data (select all the pieces, shift select the one that has the action then Ctrl L > Link Animation Data)

Answer (score 4):

You can explode inflatables using stack of modifiers including Cloth
and Force Field with both carefully tweaked and animated parameters.

[image]

1. You need to prepare your mesh for exploding by marking edges as sharp using any known method including by hand.
2. Edge Split modifier splits the mesh along the specified edges.
3. Weld - merges the split parts back but just temporarily, notice the animated Distance value.
4. Cloth Modifier with Pressure physics enabled (see the blend file)
5. Subdivision Modifier (optional) to smooth the cut edges and overall mesh.

Test the simulation and start adding key frames to important for the simulation values - turning them on and off.

[image]

Here is a Blend file to play with:

[image]